# Prove some Equivalences Norm

Tags: metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Suppose $X=R^2$ and $x=(x_1, x_2)$.

I see the following are equal EDIT: ( equivalence). why? i couldent find any proof to satisfy me. any hint or idea or proof highly appreciated.

$||x||_1= |x_1| + |x_2|$

$ ||x_2||_2= (|x_1|^2+|x_2|^2)^{1/2}$

$ ||x||_{max}= max${$|x_1|, |x_2|$}

Comment: They aren't 'equal', they are 'equivalent'.   Equal would mean they give the exact same number,  which they most certainly don't.  Equivalent means they induce the same topology.   You show equivalence by showing that one norm is bounded by the other norm both above and below (with a positive constant attached to the second norm in the above and below part).   Also as a side note, there's a much more powerful tool that's a hammer for this job that says all norms on finite dimensional real spaces are equivalent ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using $2ab\le a^2+ b^2$ and monotonicity of $x\mapsto \sqrt x$ we obtain the first
$$
\|x\|_1 = \sqrt{ (|x_1|+|x_2|)^2} = \sqrt{ |x_1|^2+2|x_1|\cdot|x_2|+ |x_2|^2} 
\le \sqrt{ 2|x_1|^2+2|x_2|^2} = \sqrt2\|x\|_2.
$$
Again by monotonicity
$$
\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{ |x_1|^2+|x_2|^2} \le \sqrt{ \|x\|_{max}^2+\|x\|_{max}^2} = \sqrt2\|x\|_{max}.
$$
Since $|x_i|\le |x_1|+|x_2|$ for all $i$,
$$
\|x\|_{max} \le \|x\|_1.
$$

Comment: The mapping $x \mapsto \sqrt x$ is monotonically increasing for $x>0$. Hence if $ a\le b$ then also $\sqrt a\le \sqrt b$. This is used in the first two inequalities.